# Why can I sort if I am using innerHTML and not outerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

My code doesn't work in Firefox.

This simple form builder isn't written in the best possible way but still, I think it should still work.

Why can't I sort the added inputs appropriate if I am using outerHTML? I want to use OuterHTML but then it can only be sorted downwards.

How can I fix and why is it behaving like it does?

```js
let id = 0;
  function add(type) {
 
 //Create an input type dynamically.
 let element = document.createElement("input");
 let div = document.createElement('div');
 let lable = document.createElement('label');
 let span = document.createElement('span');
 let br = document.createElement('br');
 
 //Assign different attributes to the element. 
 element.setAttribute("type", type);
 element.setAttribute("placeholder", "Hier Klicken");
 element.setAttribute("name", type);
 div.setAttribute("draggable", true);
 
 div.setAttribute("ondrop", "ondropself(event)");
 lable.innerHTML = "Hier drücken um zu ändern";
 
 div.style.textAlign = "right";
 div.style.width = "100%";

 var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
 
 //Append the element in page (in span).
 
 let ii = prompt("Wieviele Felder wollen sie?");
 //
 for(let j=0;j<ii;j++){
 
 id++;
 
 div.setAttribute("id", id );
 lable.setAttribute("id",id+"a");
 span.innerHTML = "X";
 span.style.textAlign = "right";
 span.setAttribute("onclick", "this.parentNode.remove(id)");
 lable.setAttribute("onclick", "labelReplace(this.parentNode.id)");
 div.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
 div.setAttribute("ondragover","allowDrop(event)");
    
    if(element.type==="button"){
        element.setAttribute("onclick","valueReplace(this.parentNode.id)");
        div.appendChild(element);
        div.appendChild(span);
        foo.appendChild(div.cloneNode(true));

    } else {

 div.appendChild(lable);
 div.appendChild(element);
 div.appendChild(span);
 
 foo.appendChild(div.cloneNode(true));
    }
 } 
}
function deletesp(el){
el.remove(id)
}

function valueReplace(a){
    let btnvalue = prompt('Button Name');
    ganzesEl = document.getElementById(a).innerHTML;
       
    ganzesEl = ganzesEl.replace('type="button"','type="button" value="'+btnvalue+'"');
    
    document.getElementById(a).innerHTML = ganzesEl;
}

function labelReplace(a){
     
    let labelText = prompt('Neuer Text');
    document.getElementById(a+"a").innerHTML = labelText;
}

function drag(idD1){
    let innerHvalue1 = document.getElementById(idD1.target.id).outerHTML;
    let idid = idD1.target.id;
    this.getIdD1 = function (){return idid};
    this.getouter =  function (){return innerHvalue1};
    
}

function allowDrop(event) {
event.preventDefault();
}

function ondropself(x){
event.preventDefault();

    const innerHvalue2 = document.getElementById(x.target.id).outerHTML;
    const innerHvalue3 = getouter();
    const ob2 =getIdD1();       
    document.getElementById(x.target.id).outerHTML = innerHvalue3;
    document.getElementById(ob2).outerHTML = innerHvalue2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<meta charset="utf-8"> 

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"> 
 <body>
 <form>
  <h2>Dynamically add textbox, and radio button in form</h2>
  <br/>
  <h3>Please select any type</h3>
  <select name="element">
   <option value="button">Button</option>
   <option value="text">TextBox</option>
   <option value="radio">Radio</option>
   <option value="number">number</option>
   <option value="reset">reset</option>
   <option value="password">password</option>
   <option value="image">image</option>
   <option value="email">email</option>
   <option value="time">time</option>
   <option value="date">date</option>

  </select>
  <input type="button" value="add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>
  <ul id="fooBar"></ul>
 </form>
 
 
 
 </body></div>
  </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<span id="okkk" class="deletespan"></span>
```

Comment: Can you please fix the snippet (unmatched `</div>`, remove unnecessary white-space, fix indentation, remove `<script>` tags that would load unreachable files, move the content of `<script>` tag with actual code into the JS part) and please remove anything that is not directly related to the problem to create a [mcve] (which some placeholder data as we don't have a valid file for testing)

Comment: [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)